# Поиск по MySQL по нескольким словам.

Tags: поиск, алгоритм, php, база-данных, mysql

Допустим в БД 2 колонки - name и sname (имя и фамилия).
Если я пишу в поле поиска "Владислав", то он найдет все строки, в которых в колонке "имя" есть "Владислав".
Поиск выполняется таким запросом:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' OR sname LIKE '%$q%'";
```

$q - в ней хранятся ключевые слова

В колонке sname есть "Безенсон" и если в поиск писать "Владислав Безенсон", то ничего таким способом не найдет. Как искать по нескольким ключевым словам в разных колонках?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут либо так

```
  $search = explode(" ", $str);

  foreach($search as $word){
      $sql[] = 'name LIKE %'.$word.'%';
      $sql[] = 'sname LIKE %'.$word.'%';
  }

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

либо регулярные выражения с помощью RLIKE (присущий только Mysql)

```
$search = str_replace(" ","|",$str);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name RLIKE "'.$search.'" OR sname RLIKE "'.$search.'"';
```

Comment: красава ))

Comment: Я выбрал второй способ. Он работает. Спасибо. Только такое дело. Он ищет совпадения в двух столбцах. Например я пишу в поиск "Влад Безенсон". Он мне находит 2 варианта: 1. Владислав Безенсон 2. Владимир Иванов, а такого быть не должно. Можно как то исправить?

Comment: @inferus-vv, заменить OR на AND, он будет искать, при условии, что и имя, и фамилия указаны в поиске. Но другая картина будет если ввести только Имя.
Первое, что приходит:

      $search = str_replace(" ","|",$str);
      $logic = $search==$str?'OR':'AND';//Если одно слово то ИЛИ имя ИЛИ фамилия, если 2 и более, то обязательно поищется и в имени, и в фамилии.

      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name RLIKE "'.$search.'" '.$logic.' sname RLIKE "'.$search.'"';

Comment: Попробую. Я заметил одну вещь. Я пишу запросы в двойных кавычках и там переменную. ("SQL $var SQL"). А вы и большинство других пишут в одинарных и "разрывают" при вставке переменных ('SQL'.$var.'SQL'). Почему так?

Comment: @inferus-vv, это оптимизация. 

Вынос переменных за строку помогает ускорить присваивание, а одинарные кавычки, для того, чтобы php не искал переменные и спец символы в строке. (Плюс если есть в строке html, его кавычки экранировать не нужно.) 

Но, по сути, как удобнее, просто я уже так привык.

Вот как раз нашёл [заметку](http://php.spb.ru/php/speed.html) по этому поводу, правда там ничего про апострофы.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT _field1_, _field2_ FROM _your_table_ WHERE 
MATCH (_field1_) AGAINST ('_text_' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо, чтобы каждое слово запроса было параметром в `sql` запросе; передавать массив запрос в `like in` ( 'param1', ..... ).

Comment: А можно по подробнее?
Если честно, не особо понял. Я просто не очень хорошо знаю PHP

Comment: Я пхп вообще не знаю =) Короче, у тебя есть  "Владислав Безенсон" - это 2 слова  "Владислав" и "Безенсон", которые ты должен передать как массив и найти их запросом вида 

    SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name LIKE in ('%$Владислав%', '%$Безенсон%') OR sname LIKE in ('%$Владислав%', '%$Безенсон%');

Comment: ну и наверно неплохо было бы проверить первым делом строгое соответствие, т.е. сделать 2 запроса SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name=param1 and sname=param2, где в param1 и param2 передать сначала "Владислав Безенсон", а потом "Безенсон Владислав" - это теоретически ускорит поиск, если юзер знает что ищет..

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую вникнуть, как-нибудь))