# Поиск слов в mySQL

Tags: запрос, mysql

Как сделать, чтобы при запросе Петя и Вася в `mySQL` искалось по связке слов и по отдельности, так как сейчас ищет только только "Петя и Вася" отдельно Петю или Васю не находит.

```
select * from name WHERE NAME LIKE $name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125545/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-mysql-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC) такой вопрос.

А вообще конкретно под вашу ситуацию, получается вот так

```
$words = explode(" ", $search_query);

foreach ($words as $word){
  $word = trim($word);

  if (strlen($word) > 3) //Слово не менее 3 символов
    $sql[] = 'NAME LIKE "%'.$word.'%"';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM name WHERE LIKE %'.$search_query.'% OR '.implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

Или опять же если RLIKE (но без проверки на длину слова).

```
$search = str_replace(" ","|", $search_query);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name RLIKE "'.$search_query.'|'.$search.'" OR sname RLIKE "'.$search.'"';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from name WHERE NAME LIKE %$name%
```